# Override existing div element that has !important by adding ID with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Html code



<div class="hamburger-menu">


CSS code

    .hamburger-menu {
Background-color: white !important;
}
```

I would like to override this by adding ID inside the div with javascript so i can add new background-color with ID selector. I am kind of new with javascript.

Anyone able to help me out?

Thank you

Comment: `!important` should be avoided whenever possible so you don't run into overriding issues. What is the reason why you have it in the first place?

Comment: My personal experience is that id selectors are *almost* always a bad idea. Once you start using them, you'll be stuck with them for every CSS rule about particular blocks of content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever u style an element with  `!important`, it will override all the existing styles even the id specified styles. [Check this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css//tryit.asp?filename=trycss_important)
2. Always try not to use id selectors, inline styles, or styles with `!important`, as it will make it very difficult to modify styles.
   [Check out this article](https://paulcpederson.com/articles/css-for-people-who-hate-css/)